# How to extract from curly brackets wth space groupped?

Tags: php, regex

I need help with regex. If i have string/text like:

"Some text {10}{20}{30} {40}

{50} some more text {60}{70} {80}

some more text {90}
"

It should give me result as array:

```
0 => {10}{20}{30}
1 => {40}
2 => {50}
3 => {60}{70}
4 => {80}
5 => {90}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: So... the `{xx}` bits should each be in their own index in an array **unless** there's no whitespace (`\s`) between them in which case they all go into one?

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
preg_match_all('/(\{[^\s]+\})/', 'Some text {10}{20}{30} {40}

{50} some more text {60}{70} {80}

some more text {90}', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/uI7zS3/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/633407

The `/`s are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The backslash is escaping the curly braces so it is the [literal character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). The `[^` is the start of a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The `\s` is any whitespace. The `]` closes the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The `+` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), allowing one or more of the non whitespaces.

Comment: It is pretty old and i forget to mark it as correct answer (sorry). But, i have question now. It works for one server, and for another it shows "html" tags too in between and I need it without html tags. I tried with flags but doesn't help

Comment: @p3ro Can you post an example of what you have?

Comment: https://eval.in/763811 here is... it shows td's and it groupped {40} and {50} in same group but it shouldn't. Each cell in this case has placeholders group. First is 10,20,30, second is 40, third is 50 etc.

Comment: If you can pretty print the mark up you could use `strip_tags`. https://eval.in/763815

Comment: that's true.. i find that already.. strip_tags but point is, it puts 40 and 50 in same group even after that...

Comment: group 1: 10,20,30
group 2: 40
group 3: 50
gorup 4: 60,70,80
group 5: 90

Comment: this is how it should look..and in array i get 40 and 50 in same array key

Comment: You didnt pretty print it. There's no whitespace between those elements. Look at the provided link.

Comment: before: <td>{40}</td> <td>{50}</td> without space in between <td>{40}</td><td>{50}</td>

Comment: if there is no space between </td><td> it shows them in same group

Comment: It wouldn't work because the regex is looking for non-whitespaces.

Comment: you say if there is no space it will not work? is there some way to make it work in this case too, if there is <td> or not

Comment: How about this hideous approach? `strip_tags(str_replace('><', '> <', `https://eval.in/763823

Comment: Hmm that's not bad.. i was thinking about some regex to put space between td's but your idea works too..thx i will try it